# mysql, Create Column with a default value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've a table `item` that has some columns that are `nullable`.
To one of them `type`, I'd like to automatically insert a `default` value (instead of a `NULL`) whenever a new record in inserted in the table and do not specify a value for that column.

Can it be done without affecting the existing data?
The `type` column is a `varchar`.

I can update the current `nulls`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to `ALTER` column set a default value.

```
ALTER TABLE `T` MODIFY `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT 'default';
```

then insert by  `DEFAULT` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO  T (type) VALUES (DEFAULT);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ab468/1/0)**:

Answer (score 1):

This query will work for you.

For update table.

```
ALTER TABLE `column_name` CHANGE `tab` `my_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

For insert table

```
CREATE TABLE `db_name`.`Tbale_name` ( `demo` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0');
```