# how to specify default value for foreign key reference in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose there is a two tables "User" and "Product", so there is also a foreign key, that means, that one user can have multiple products, like:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (

  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

  ProductId PRIMARY KEY,  
  Products FOREIGN KEY(ProductId) REFERENCES product(id)

)

CREATE TABLE "product"(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
)
```

The problem is when I'm creating a new user I don't specify `ProductId`, (because for example product does not exist yet) it always it throws an exception, that `ProductId` has a unique constraint and should be not null.

So What I Need to Put Inside ProductId?

Because I don't specify any value for it when creating `User`, it throws unique constraint error, but without this Field I cannot have a foreign key between two tables, so it cannot be removed.

So, the question is "How can I Specify Default Value for This Reference "ProductId" Field in My "User" model, when creating an user object, in order to avoid this unique constraint error."

Comment: Well, you will need to create the product first. But a column named `productid` as the primary key for a table named `user` sounds extremely weird to me. Why isn't `user.id` the primary key? And why is a user only related to a single product? That sounds like a strange decision to me as well.

Comment: this question telles you how to create a column with a default value: [mysql, Create Column with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320243/mysql-create-column-with-a-default-value). It should have enough info to specify a default value for your column .  (But, I think, the problem lies elsewhere...)

Comment: Sorry, I've been using ORMs for a long time, and pretty rarely been dealing with a raw sql, I recently switched to Golang, and there is a bit another implementation of foreign keys, so I'm getting used to it, so WHAT I WANT IS `to make "one object" have a lot of another's` :)

Comment: If a user can be "have" many products, you need a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) between user and product. If a product can only ever be "owned" by  a single user, then product should have a foreign key to user. Your current model would allow a user to "have" only a single product.